# Set excel slicer to todays date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date slicer connected to a pivottable and two pivotcharts. I want this slicer to automatically filter to todays date. I recon I have to do this using VBA code, so I googled and found the following code, from this answer:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2542f1dc-ca62-4ea4-b686-bfa78b53c699/automatically-select-last-available-date-slicer-value-when-opening-workbook?forum=exceldev

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim today As Date
    today = Now
    Dim todayString As String
    todayString = Format$(today, "d mmm yyyy")

    Dim item As SlicerItem

    For Each item In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Date Slicer").SlicerItems
        If item.Name = todayString Then
            item.Selected = True
        Else
            item.Selected = False
        End If
    Next item

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

However, when I applied this code, I got the following error:

```
Run-time error '2004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Does anyone got working code to manipulate the date slicer, or know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lars-rotgers Answer over is 100_% correct for cases where there is no pivottable, but for cases where there is a pivottable this is the right solution:

```
Sub SetTodaysDate()

    Dim today As Date
    today = Now
    Dim todayString As String
    todayString = Format$(today, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
        "[Period].[Date].&[" & todayString & "]")
End Sub
```

The [Period].[Date]has to correspond to the dimensions etc in your cube.

Answer (score 1):

The name `Date Slicer` is probably incorrect. If I record a macro and select a date, then view my code, I get this:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date")
    .SlicerItems("1/1/2015").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("10/5/2015").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("10/26/2015 13:46").Selected = False
End With
```

So the object name for the slicer is in my macro code `Slicer_Date`. Try to record a macro to find the object name for the slicer. Then use that name in your code above.

**Edit for comment**

I have changed the code a little bit to fit it for my date format:

```
Sub SlicerSelectToday()

    Dim today As Date
    today = Now
    Dim todayString As String
    todayString = Format$(today, "m/d/yyyy") ' I have US date

    Dim item As SlicerItem

    For Each item In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").SlicerItems
        If item.Name = todayString Then
            item.Selected = True
        Else
            item.Selected = False
        End If
    Next item

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

This `sub` is working, and selects the date of today in the slicer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After doing what you recommended, I still get the same error when trying to run this sub.

Comment: The code is working at me. At first I got an error because I renamed it to `Date_Slicer`, the correct name is `Slicer_Date`. Can you double check that the name is correct?

Comment: Yes, When I record the macro I get:
Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Dato").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
        "[Periode].[Dato].&[04.10.2015]")
End Sub´

I use Slicer_Dato as a name.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a reaction to your comment.

Comment: Thank you - It seems like this errors if you select an other date, then run the macro? Then all dates up to this gets selected.

Comment: Try adding `ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").ClearAllFilters` before the `For Each` loop.

Comment: Thank you, this works partly, but it seems like VBA canta ccess the items to a slicer connected to a pivottable/cube using the function in your code.