# How to find Dimensions in cube for Excel slicer

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers

I am trying to figure out how to get the dimensions of the cube for my slicer. I have tried next to everything to get it to work, but with no success.

The code below is what I am using to have the slicer set the day to today's date only.

```
Dim today As Date
today = Now
Dim todayString As String
todayString = Format$(today, "mm/dd/yyyy")
ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Created_on").ClearManualFilter
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Created_on").VisibleSlicerItemsList=
Array( _  
"[Period].[Date].&[" & todayString & "]") ' This is where the error occurs.
```

The above code was found on this site at the following link:
[Set excel slicer to todays date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345980/set-excel-slicer-to-todays-date)

I tried to modify it so that the

```
"[Period].[Date].&[" & todayString & "]")
```

was in this format:
    "[Period]/[Date]/&[" & todayString & "]")

Created two more dimensions to be:
Year and month and modified it like this:
    dim month
    month=format$(today,"mm")
    todaystring =format$(today,"dd")
    Year=format$(today,"yyyy")

```
"[Month]/&["& todaystring & "]" & [Year]")
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: After hours of tinkering around, I was not able to figure out how to determine what the cube values are so I used a different code found on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of tinkering around, I was not able to figure out how to determine what the cube values are so I used a different code found on this site.

At this link: [Set excel slicer to todays date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345980/set-excel-slicer-to-todays-date)

Sub SlicerSelectToday()

```
Dim today As Date
today = Now
Dim todayString As String
todayString = Format$(today, "m/d/yyyy") ' I have US date

Dim item As SlicerItem

For Each item In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").SlicerItems
    If item.Name = todayString Then
        item.Selected = True
    Else
        item.Selected = False
    End If
Next item

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

End Sub

EDIT:
If possible avoid looping through all of the date values because it takes longer. I would highly recommend recording a macro of the tasks that you wish to complete with the Pivot Tables then edit the macro for your needs. For example record a macro of your actions while you apply a date filter "Date Filter>Yesterday" value to only show yesterday's data.
Something similar to what I did in this link [Excel 2013 VBA Pivot Table Select Only Top 5 Items With Ties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721069/excel-2013-vba-pivot-table-select-only-top-5-items-with-ties/45760395#45760395).
I hope this helps someone.