# VBA Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba

I used [Set excel slicer to today's date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345980/set-excel-slicer-to-todays-date) as reference to try to build a similar function: the slicer always pick up today's (well in my case yesterday's) date, but I always had the error'438'. Here is the code I'm trying:

```
Sub SlicerSelectToday()

Dim today As Date
today = Now - 1
Dim todayString As String
todayString = Format$(today, "m/d/yyyy")
'MsgBox (todayString)


Dim item As SlicerItem

'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Collector").Activate
'ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_RptDate").ClearManualFilter

For Each item In       Worksheets("Collector").SlicerCaches("Slicer_RptDate").SlicerItems
    If item.Name = todayString Then
        item.Selected = True
    Else
        item.Selected = False
    End If
Next item

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Any suggestion where I coded wrong?

Comment: what line raises the error?

Comment: For Each item In Worksheets("Collector").SlicerCaches("Slicer_RptDate").SlicerItems it's as if item is not recognized though, when I did row by row test

Comment: Won't fix the error, but the body of the loop could be `item.Selected = item.Name = todayString` instead of a whole `If...Then...Else` block.

Answer (score 2):

[David Zemens got your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41815992/1188513).

Here's how to avoid repeating it.

Looking at this line:

> ```
> For Each item In Worksheets("Collector").SlicerCaches("Slicer_RptDate").SlicerItems
> ```

If we made every statement explicit, it would look like this:

```
For Each item In Worksheets.Item("Collector").SlicerCaches.Item("Slicer_RptDate").SlicerItems
```

In other words:

```
Worksheets.Item("Collector") _
          .SlicerCaches.Item("Slicer_RptDate") _
                       .SlicerItems
```

That's a lot of member accesses for a single instruction.

By introducing intermediate variables...

```
Dim collectorSheet As Worksheet
Set collectorSheet = Worksheets("Collector")

Dim rptDateSlicerCache As SlicerCache
Set rptDateSlicerCache = collectorSheet.SlicerCaches("Slicer_RptDate") '*

For Each item In rptDateSlicerCache.SlicerItems
    '...
Next
```

...you could have noticed *while typing* the line marked with a `'*` comment, that *IntelliSense* doesn't offer `SlicerCaches` as a member of `collectorSheet`.

Why? Because this:

```
Worksheets("Collector")
```

Returns an `Object` - and from that point on, you're on your own: *IntelliSense* can't help you with autocompletion, because members of an `Object` aren't resolved until runtime.

By assigning that object to a `Worksheet` variable, you give yourself compile-time checking, and avoid that pesky runtime error 438.

Comment: Teach a man to fish... :)  Awesome explanation for debugging this!

Answer (score 1):

`SlicerCaches` is a property of the `Workbook` class, not the `Worksheet` class, as you've configured your code. Try instead:

`For Each item In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_RptDate").SlicerItems`

Comment: Thanks. But then I've got Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error, on the same row.

Comment: @Viviannne IMO that most likely means that there is no `"Slicer_RptDate"` slicer item in the `SlicerCaches` collection at the time you're checking.

Comment: But in the "Name to use in formulas"(slicer setting), it shows as "Slicer_RptDate" and in VBA, I listed "ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_RptDate").ClearManualFilter " before the for loop, it actually worked.

Comment: Try Ctrl+G (immediate pane), then type `?ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_RptDate") Is Nothing` - that will either print `False` (in which case I'm puzzled), or reproduce the runtime error. Once you've narrowed down the error to that one specific call, try `?ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Count` - if that outputs `0`, then there's a problem. If that's `1`, then do `?ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(1).Name` - that *should* give you the name it's expecting to see. [note, I'm not very familiar with the SlicerCaches API, so actual member names might be different]

Comment: Mat, the return value of ?ThisWorkbook.Slicercaches(1).Name is correct. I am wondering if I put "Dim item As SlicerItem" in a wrong place? Because when I tested step by step, looked like this Dim sentence was never caught some how

Comment: `Dim` statement can go *literally* anywhere in the subroutine, though for style purposes it's usually preferred to put it at the top. Since this answer has solved the original question, I might suggest asking a separate question to troubleshoot the 1004 error.

Comment: Just a guess but is your slicer connected to a PivotTable?

Comment: Yes. So that's why it won't work? -- Actually I have a group of PowerPivot dataset based on SQLs, and this slicer links to several PivotTables pulling dax measures in PowerPivot

Comment: @Vivianne that is *excactly* what's described in the *accepted* answer on the other question you linked to :)

Comment: Sorry still don't get it. If a slicer is linked to a pivot then we cannot control it in this way?

Comment: @Viviannne http://stackoverflow.com/a/33362892/1467082

Comment: This is beyond my ability to really answer at this point, your question has morphed from its original state (which we've solved). For further troubleshooting, please ask a new/separate question.

Comment: And to answer your last comment, No, it seems you cannot control it in *this* way, you should control it in the way given by the *actually accepted answer* on the other question, which is different from the answer you're attempting to implement.